# Any hop recommendations for a single hop PA out of these options

Tags: hops, ale, pale

I'm about to brew an American Pale Ale or Pale Ale. I'm only considering a single hop on this time around. Any recommendation out of these options listed below? It’s what I have left. I'd love to go a little experimental. But I know some can lack a bit of complexity for single hop ale.

- Saaz
- Huell Melon
- Polaris
- Columbus/Tomahawk
- Azacca
- Centennial
- Hallertau Blanc
- Jester

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an American Pale Ale, I'd stick with American hops.

Saaz is *the* classic Czech Pilsner hop, Hallertau is a German noble hop. If you use those, you may end up with something between a Pale Ale and a Czech or German Pilsner respectively.

I just had a Azacca SMASH and that was great, so my personal favorite would be an Azacca pale ale.

Comment: Yes, I recently did an Azacca. That time around it turned out a little bit differently than I expected. For the most part in a good way. I thought it would be closer to a Citra or Cascade. I actually went with Jester this time around. That might have been a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

If I were to choose only one hop for an APA, it would be Centennial, similar to other hops specifically used for an APA, a little less “grapefruit” notes then Cascade, but still fruity with some pine notes with a clean finish.  This one will work and you’ll be pleased with the results.

Comment: Yes, Centennial is a beast for sure.